# Recreate specific plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, physics, homework

[image]

Can anyone help on this ?

I did this

```
c = 2.998 10^8;
h = 6.62607015 10^-34;
Kb = 1.380649 10^-23;


i[\[Lambda]_,
   T_] := ((2 Pi h c^2)/(\[Lambda]^5 (Exp[(h c)/(\[Lambda] Kb T)] -
      1)));


M = Plot[i[\[Lambda], 3000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Green},
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Green ];

N = [i[\[Lambda], 4000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic ,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Blue, Dashed},
    Filling -> Axis];

O =  [i[\[Lambda], 5000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic ,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Orange}];

Show[M , N , O, GridLines -> Automatic , PlotRange -> Automatic ,
  Frame -> True , AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda][m], (watts/m^3)},
  Epilog -> {Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=3000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.23 10^-7,
      5.42 10^13}],
    Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=4000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.23 10^-7,
      1.64 10^13}],
    Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=5000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.75 10^-7,
      3.90 10^13}]}] // Quiet
```

and I get this "is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision 
may be lost". Can anyone help please

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Post the code you have tried.

Comment: Have you already seen `PlanckRadiationLaw[]`?

Comment: I would recommend not using capital letters to start your symbol names. `N`, for example, is a built-in which I would definitely not want to overwrite.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Apart from the comments you already got, look at `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"`.

Comment: Please improve your first question, which might be literally the same one.  [These should probably be merged, since this one has an answer.]

Comment: I guess I meant it should have been an edit.

Answer (score 6):

This is a possibility for what you want:

```
c = 2.998  10^8 ;
h = 6.62607015 10^-34 ;
Kb = 1.380649 10^-23 ;


i[l_, T_] := (2 Pi h c^2)/(l^5 (Exp[(h c)/(l Kb T)] - 1));


Plot[{i[l, 3000], i[l, 4000],i[l, 5000]}, {l, 0, 2.5 10^-6}, PlotRange -> All]// Quiet
```

[image]

I added //Quiet in the end because it complained about having to deal with such small numbers.

For styling the plot (color, filling, labeling...) you should take a look at the options of the Plot function in the documentation. Ask if you need any help with that.

Comment: yes please, I did it first and kept getting failed and now I'm getting an empty graph, I'm sorry if it's to much but I'm new to this :(

Comment: @user77551 To get the exact graph you want, simply copy the code I wrote and add more options, like Filling-> Axis, Frame-> True and so on. You can find all the options of the Plot function very easily in the documentation. If your code isn't working, I think it's better if you post it here so people can point out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also, pay attention to the fact that you defined your constants wrong, you can't use "x" as "times" because it will be interpreted as a variable. Same thing goes for the units. Notice how the constants are defined in the code I posted.

Comment: I keep getting this massage " is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision" , Can I show my work and you tell me where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of problems in your code.

Mathematica reserves uppercase `N` and `O`, you can't reassign them (well, at least not easily).  You don't really need them.

Your code doesn't define 3 plots, so the `Show` can't show 3 curves.
That said you can avoid the `Show` completely.

Also, you've used `Insert` instead of `Inset` in the `Epilog` assignments.

```
c = 2.998 10^8;
h = 6.62607015 10^-34;
Kb = 1.380649 10^-23;

i[\[Lambda]_,
   T_] := ((2 Pi h c^2)/(\[Lambda]^5 (Exp[(h c)/(\[Lambda] Kb T)] -
      1)));

Plot[{i[\[Lambda], 3000], i[\[Lambda], 4000], 
   i[\[Lambda], 5000]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5*10^-6},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> {
    {Thickness[0.005], Green},
    {Thickness[0.005], Blue, Dashed},
    {Thickness[0.005], Orange}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Lambda][m]", "(watts/m^3)"},
  Filling -> {2 -> Axis, 3 -> 2},
  FillingStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> Automatic, 3 -> Orange},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[
     Framed[Style["T=3000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.23*10^-7, 
      0.75*10^13}], 
    Inset[Framed[Style["T=4000K", 10], 
      Background -> White], {8.23*10^-7, 1.64*10^13}], 
    Inset[Framed[Style["T=5000K", 10], 
      Background -> White], {8.75*10^-7, 3.90*10^13}]}
  ] // Quiet
```

[image]

You need to do some additional formatting of the Epilog style and the placement, but I'll leave that to you.